# Save a bitstream to a file using python

Tags: python, bitstring, bitstream, h.265

I need to output an h.265 (or hevc, is the same) bit-stream onto an str file in python.

I have a bitstream file and i select some data from this file to save it to a new one. I use [bitstring](https://code.google.com/p/python-bitstring/) module to process the bitstream file.

**Edit:** My question is how to create a new bitstream file and insert data into.

Comment: What is your quesstion?

Comment: Please show the code you have, and what part is causing you problems.

Comment: Why not just open the file as binary and do `struct.pack` to pack characters, etc. into binary?

Comment: @ZWiki Can you give me a simple example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the part about Joining BitArrays (base class of BitStream) in [this](https://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/slicing.html) part of the bitstring documentation. How to join the substreams depends on how you have them in the first place.

For writing the bitstream to a file, use the method 'toFile' of the [Bits class](https://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/constbitarray.html), which is a base class of BitStream.

```
f = open('fileToWriteTo', 'wb')
bitstreamObject.tofile(f)
```

If you want to write multiple substreams one after another, you can open the file in append mode the next times you write something.

```
f = open('fileToWriteTo', 'ab')
nextSubstream.tofile(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html)

A quick example:

```
import struct
characters = "Hello World"
with open(filepath, 'wb') as f:
    for char in characters:
        # @B means to pack native (LSB or MSB) to size unsigned char (1 byte)
        packed = struct.pack('@B', char)
        f.write(packed)
```

Comment: Thank you but I find it easier to use the solution above.